# Prove: $f$ is injective if and only if for any non-empty set $C$ and for all functions $g, h : C \to A$ such that $f ◦ g = f ◦ h$ we have $g = h$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, elementary-functions

I’m attempting to prove this exercise for my elementary analysis class, however, I am having difficulty deconstructing the iff statement. Any help in understanding how the implications are working would be great. I’m also lost on how $f$ being injective makes the functions $g$ and $h$ equal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

So, you want to prove that $f$ being injective implies that, whenever $f\circ g = f \circ h$, you will consequently have $g=h$. You also want to prove the converse: whenever you have $f\circ g = f\circ h \implies g = h$, you want to show that this implies $f$ is an injective function.

**For the forward implication,** one of the basic properties injective functions have is the existence of a left inverse. That is, if $f : A\to B$ is injective, there exists a function $\bar f : B\to A$ such that $\bar f \circ f = 1_A$. With this in mind, try to see if you can make this fact useful.

**For the converse,** recall the definition of injective functions. One of the definitions you may have is that $f$ is injective if $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$ for all $x,y$ in the domain of $f$. We're given that $f(g(x)) = f(h(x))$ for all $x$ in the domains of $g,h$, and that $g(x)=h(x)$ is implied as a result. How might you use this fact when it comes to the definition of injective?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

One way is obvious. If $f$ is injective then the condition holds by definition. to prove the converse suppose $f(x)=f(y)$. We want to show that $x=y$. We have to choose appropriate $C,g$ and $h$ and use the hypothesis. Note that if $f(g(z))=x$ and $f(h(z))=y$ for all $z \in C$ we get $x=y$ as required. For this we  take $C=\{x,y\}$ and define $g$ to be the constant function $x$ and $h$ to be the constant function $y$.

Comment: Doesn’t this violate the fact that it must hold for all functions g and h?